# How do i properly deploy a Peerjs app to heroku

Tags: node.js, express, video-streaming, backend, peerjs

I am trying to deploy a zoom clone app,a video chatting app. It works fine locally and as i have peer installed globally. I saved it as a dependency so heroku could install it as well but i still keep getting an application error when its deployed.

```
const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
    secure: true,
    host: 'myappname@herokuapp.com',
    port: '443'
})
```

My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "zoom_clone",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "preshy jones",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "peer": "^0.5.3",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

I still keep getting an application error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to deploy peer-js serve on heroku and use that url as a host in your app.
you can get information about deploying peerjs on heroku from here https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/peers/peerjs-server